# Statistical test to assess that a bunch of point diverge from background distribution

Tags: r, outliers

I've to set of points. First a set of points representing the background, that are very close to the identity line (slope=1). And a second set of points that seems to diverge from this identity line (points in red). How can I test wheter these points diverge from this identity line ? Is a ks.test ok ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What would you apply the KS test to?  It's a test of the distribution of *univariate,* not bivariate, data.  You would make some progress by converting your data into a distance from the line: just look at `r[,2]-r[,1]`.  Unless you have a specific hypothesis about the distribution of these distances, the KS test won't help--but it should become obvious what to do.

Comment: one idea is as you mention to compute the vertical distance between the points and the abline. The hypothesis is that the distances should be close to 0

Comment: Since you phrased your question in terms of "closeness" to and "divergence" from the line, a more natural distance would be the (signed) *Euclidean* distance.  This would treat the two coordinates on an equal footing, too, accommodating variation in both of them simultaneously.  The difference of coordinates is, up to a constant factor, that signed Euclidean distance.  (The purpose of a signed distance is to distinguish low outliers from high outliers. This distinction makes a difference in many outlier tests.)

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. And with these distances, wich test did you recommend ? My H0 is that distances are = 0.

Comment: You might consider exploring our [tag:outliers] tag for threads that discuss this problem.  If you look hard enough, I expect you will discover that the choice of test depends on your expectations about the outliers: how many there could be, how extreme they might be, whether they will be high, low, or in both directions; and it will depend on your expectations about how the non-outlying values are distributed.  (That's why [entire books have been written about the subject](http://books.google.com/books/about/Outliers_in_Statistical_Data.html?id=B44QAQAAIAAJ).)